# What is the de-facto standard keyboard shortcut for auto-completion?

Tags: autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I want to know which keyboard shortcut is used popularly for auto-completion in order to avoid confusion.

For example, in Emacs, the completion is C-M-i or M-TAB.
The completion is TAB in sublimeText, Ctrl-Space in Eclipse.

Is there any de-facto standard shortcut for completion?
If not, which shortcut should I use in your opinion?

Comment: You give the answer yourself: There are different keystrokes used for auto completion. There is no "standard". Asking for a opinion is not a perfect stackoverflow question. Its answer: Your mileage may vary. I.e. if you write something for the command line then you should maybe use TAB.

Comment: I want to maximize the probability of meeting same shortcut when using new application. In most case, each software allows modifying the keystroke for auto completion. I want to integrate the keystrokes, and my question is: which keystroke eases modification work?